# Pass Arraylist as argument to function

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist A of Integer type. I created it as:

```
ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now, I want to pass it as an argument to function `AnalyseArray()`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
public void AnalyseArray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
  // Do something
}
...
ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
AnalyseArray(A);
```

Comment: Why did you choose to limit the methods usefulness with an ArrayList instead of the more general List?

Comment: The method does read AnalyseArray, so it would make since to take something that internally uses an array. Maybe what it's doing inside the method is sensitive to the O of the get() methods, so passing a LinkedList would be bad.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is already posted but note that this will pass the ArrayList by reference. So if you make any changes to the list in the function it will be affected to the original list also.

```
<access-modfier> <returnType> AnalyseArray(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
//analyse the list
//return value
}
```

call it like this:

```
x=AnalyseArray(list);
```

or pass a copy of ArrayList:

```
x=AnalyseArray(list.clone());
```

Comment: just for completeness's sake... write the answer too......

Answer (score 2):

Define it as

```
<return type> AnalyzeArray(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how and where you declared your array list. If it is an instance variable in the same class like your AnalyseArray() method you don't have to pass it along. The method will know the list and you can simply use the A in whatever purpose you need.

If they don't know each other, e.g. beeing a local variable or declared in a different class,  define that your AnalyseArray() method needs an ArrayList parameter

```
public void AnalyseArray(ArrayList<Integer> theList){}
```

and then work with theList inside that method. But don't forget to actually pass it on when calling the method.`AnalyseArray(A);`

PS: Some maybe helpful Information to [Variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm) and [parameters](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/parameters.html).